# Draw over app and just manage scrolling events in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to draw view over other apps with transparent theme filling width and height.

I need to pass my touch events to the app that i draw on. But there is a restriction -- only scrolling (up and down) has to pass to app, NOT clicks , double taps etc.

When user clicks something, there shouldnt be any action on the app that i draw on.
But, user can scroll up & down in the app so he can view what's going on.

How can i achieve this?